# How to show search results on rails event_calendar?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I'm new to Rails and I am using rails [event_calendar](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) plug-in on my project. I implement it basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete ) operations on events. But now I need to show my search results on event_calendar. So please can some one give me an idea to implement this on event_calendar ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the event_calendar README:

The EventCalendar.new method accepts a hash or block of options, for example:

```
@event_calendar = EventCalendar.new(2009, 10, :id => 'calendar', :events => Event.all)

@event_calendar = EventCalendar.new(2009, 10) do |c|
  c.id = 'calendar'
  c.events = Event.all
end
```

So, instead of Event.all, just use whatever code you're using to get your filtered results.

Comment: Where do I need to add those modifications ??

Comment: @event_calendar.to_html  -- just like in the documenation.  Here's a link:  https://github.com/shuber/event_calendar

Comment: No I'm using https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar event calendar so how could I do It in that calendar ?? Can you give me some suggestion